# How to get apt-cacher-ng to download AND cache packages from Apt HTTPS repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, cache, apt-cacher-ng

Typically Apt packages are served over bare HTTP and the downloaded contents are verified with GPG signatures. This makes it easy for [apt-cacher-ng](https://wiki.debian.org/AptCacherNg) to proxy the HTTP connections and add the downloaded packages to its cache.

apt-cacher-ng is unable to directly MITM an HTTPS connection created by Apt. It is possible to [configure HTTPS connections to pass through](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/05/05/using-apt-cacher-ng-with-ssl-tls/) apt-cacher-ng, but then the contents are not cached--they are re-downloaded from the remote server every time. This quickly gets annoying when rebuilding Docker containers that install many packages from Apt repositories served over HTTPS.

Is there a way to get apt-cacher-ng to cache packages downloaded from HTTPS repositories?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the URL of your apt-cacher-ng service is `http://localhost:3000` and you are storing it in the bash variable `${LOCAL_APT_CACHE_URL}`.

Then you have to rewrite your `sources.list` file and the `sources.list.d` directory files with the following two transformations:

#### HTTP

This command rewrites an Apt repository URL at `http://example.com` to `http://localhost:3000/example.com`:

```bsh
find /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ \
-type f -exec sed -Ei 's!http://!'${LOCAL_APT_CACHE_URL}'/!g' {} \;
```

#### HTTPS

This command rewrites an Apt repository at `https://example.com` to `http://localhost:3000/HTTPS///example.com`. apt-cacher-ng receives the HTTP request and then initiates its own HTTPS request--removing the need for any MITM or passthrough. HTTPS packages are cached properly.

```bsh
find /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ \
-type f -exec sed -Ei 's!https://!'${LOCAL_APT_CACHE_URL}'/HTTPS///!g' {} \;
```

---

This transformation has to be done for any new repositories that are added later on--whether by directly modifying the `sources.list` or through a utility like `add-apt-repository`.

Comment: is there a way to just do this through the proxy only?